# How to stop WebKit recursively reducing font size?

Tags: css, webkit, font-size

I'm using *WebKit*, and I'm trying to reduce the font size in one element and all it contents. Here is an example of the element:

```html
<div id="element">
<div>The element has a sub-element with <i>italic</i>, <strong>strong</strong> and other tags.</div>
</div>
```

This CSS doesn't reduce the font at all:

```css
#element {
    font-size: smaller;
}
```

If I select only the internal `<div>`, the font size doesn't reduce in `<i>` and `<strong>`:

```css
#element div {
    font-size: smaller;
}
```

I cannot select each tag individually because I don't know all possible nested tags. The last chance is to use asterisk:

```css
#element * {
    font-size: smaller;
}
```

But this CSS works even worse: it recursively reduces the size of each nested tag.

This behavior is very unexpected, and cannot be reproduced in Chrome. Is that a bug of WebKit? Is that possible to disable the "feature" of recursively reducing the font size?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `> *` selector

```
#element > * {
    font-size: smaller;
}
```

This will select every tag which is a direct child of `#element`, but won't go any level deeper.

Selector you've written - `#element *` - applies styles to every element inside a `#element` no matter if it's a direct child or very nested element. So this happnes in your example: `<div>` have smaller font size than `#element`, `<i>` have smaller font size than `<div>` (so now it is twice smaller than `#element`) and so on.

You can read more about selectors [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp).

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. For sure the selector works and selects the direct children... but the grand children are not affected by the rule at all. For example, if the rule decreases the size 50%, the children become 50%, but the grand children are 100% again. Looks like this is a WebKit bug.

Comment: Ok, It turned out that I misunderstood your problem. Now i see that it is weird that `#element div` selector doesn't affect your tags. Did you try to use `rem`/`em` units?

Answer (score 0):

My element selectors `#element` and `#element div` works as it should. That is, all the elements inside are reduced. Try to run the snippet code I wrote below, if everything works as it should, then most likely you have a different font size specified somewhere else in the code. If it does not decrease in the snippet, then there may be a problem in the browser. Write in a comment if there are any difficulties, I am ready to help you figure it out.

```css
#element {
    font-size: smaller;
}

#element2 div {
    font-size: smaller;
}
```

```html
<div id="element"><div>If you accept font-size smaller to id #element then everything is reduced as needed including <i>italic</i> and <strong>strong</strong></div></div>

<div id="element2"><div>If you accept font-size smaller to div inside #element2 then everything is reduced as needed also including <i>italic</i> and <strong>strong</strong></div></div>
```

Comment: My question is about how this works in WebKit and how to avoid its undesired behavior.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Maybe it will help you to make the rest of the text as a span `<div id="element">
<div><span>The element has a sub-element with</span> <i>italic</i><span>,</span> <strong>strong</strong> <span>and other tags.</span></div>
</div>` and then use `#element div > *` for all elements. Not the best solution, but most likely working

Comment: :) No, that is not a solution.